# Django + GoogleAppEngine Error: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

So I am learning how to use Django and I am using Google App Engine. I have the latest Django directory in the same directory as my main.

When I run it from my local it works fine. But when I deploy it and run it from the webpage, I get a Server Error.

Here is the code for my main.py and settings.py

main.py:

```
import os
import settings
from django.template import Context, Template
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, World!\n')
        t = Template('It is now {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}')
        c = Context({ })
        self.response.out.write(t.render(c))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

settings.py:

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Whitehorse'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
```

Comment: I get this error, whenever the memcache is flushed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble with the environment variable then try configuring the settings directly (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module)

```
import settings
import django.conf

# Filter out all the non-setting attributes of the settings module
settingsKeys = filter(lambda name: str(name) == str(name).upper(), 
                      dir(settings))

# copy all the setting values from the settings module into a dictionary
settingsDict = dict(map(lambda name: (name, getattr(settings, name)), 
                        settingsKeys))

django.conf.settings.configure(**settingsDict)
```